# Defining variable Source range for pivot chart code in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I have recorded a macro for pivot table and chart. Now I what to change the range as per the changes in the rows and columns of the source sheet.

The code from the recorded macro is:

```
SourceData:= _
        "DATA INPUT SHEET!R2C1:R23C12", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
```

Any way out to change the Range `R2C1:R23C12` to `Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(FinalRow,8+NoBids))`, where `Finalrow` is the last row of the source sheet and `NoBids` is to the no. of columns to be added after the 8th column of the source sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, try the code below:

```
SourceData:= "DATA INPUT SHEET!" & Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(FinalRow, 8 + NoBids)).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
```

If you want to learn more about the `Range.Address` Property, read [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx)